# nginx configuring location variable

Tags: nginx

I want to configure my nginx to serve requests like:

http://example.com/vk-lang-training/

by returning `/var/www/vk-lang-training/build/index.html`

My configuration snippet is

```
    location /vk-lang-training/ {
        root /var/www/vk-lang-training/build;
        index index.html;
    }
```

But I got 404 error and see in my error.log

```
2019/12/11 09:56:19 [error] 8434#8434: *2 "/var/www/vk-lang-training/build/vk-lang-training/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory)
```

As I could see it calls `/var/www/vk-lang-training/build/vk-lang-training/index.html` instead of `/var/www/vk-lang-training/build/index.html`

How to return `/var/www/vk-lang-training/build/index.html` ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I found sulution.

Instead of `root` I have to use `alias`. Like this

```
    location /vk-lang-training/ {
        alias /var/www/vk-lang-training/build/;
        index index.html;
    }
```